# How to update contents on a webpage?

Tags: php, html

Obviously this is done through a user just simple editing an HTML file, but when we deliver this website to a customer, what way would be good for them to just simple update contents without having to go into the HTML file?

For example, **"Today's Horoscope"** would obviously need an update everyday. How do we update the contents without having to just edit the HTML file? A link or a documentation would be a nice, Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to update the content to database.
My suggestion is just learn php mysql.

For your Example, You won't update **Today's Horoscope** in html file, you will update it on your mysql table and retrieve the data from that table.

Good to start with [this](http://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/sql/MySQL_Beginner.html).

Answer (score 2):

Look in to CMS solutions like Joomla or Wordpress.  It sounds like you are looking for a dynamic website.  These solutions will allow you to have an intuitive backend for your authors who may not be very "code savvy".  Much easier and proficient than static html.